# Vigor2925 - How to manage devices connected via secondary Wi-Fi router

Tags: ipv4, ieee-802.11

I'm looking for some help on how to manage devices which are connected via a 2nd router that is used as a Wi-Fi AP.

The setup is as follows:

- TPLink TD-W8968 Wi-Fi router (as AP) is connected to our switch
- Various (authorised) devices connected to the switch
- Switch connected to our Vigor2925 Router

The Wi-Fi AP has been mapped to an IP address on the router (`.100`) and has a public (passworded) Wi-Fi connection to which users can connect.

Users connecting to Wi-Fi show up on the Vigor as other IP addresses, e.g ., `192.168.1.16`.

How can I manage (QoS, bandwidth/session limits) any device which has connected via the Wi-Fi AP?

I set a bandwidth limit for `.100`, but since other devices are given their own IP addresses on the Vigor router, I'm guessing it may not be affecting them as it should?

Do I need to maybe use settings on the Wi-Fi AP to manage the devices that connect through it, or can it be done with the Vigor?

Answer (score 1):

Two options immediately spring to mind:

1. Set the Wi-Fi router into bridge mode and manage on the main router.  You should have a separate VLAN for your Wi-Fi if you want to treat that traffic separately.
2. Manage on the Wi-Fi router.  The Wi-Fi router may not be capable of this if it is a consumer-grade device, in which case it would be off-topic for this forum.

Comment: Hmm, the WiFi router is pretty basic. I'm not sure what "mode" it is in, but I'll see if I can set it to bridge. Lets say it is already in bridge mode, how do I go about making the VLAN exactly on my Vigor router? And can I leave the WiFi AP plugged in via the switch, or does it needs to go into one of the specific ports on the Vigor router?

Comment: Your Wi-Fi router is not in bridge mode if it is assigning IP addresses to its clients. According to the datasheet, the Vigor router does VLANs, but I don't know the details. You would set up a trunk to the switch from the Vigor, and you would set the particular switch port where the Wi-Fi is connected to the Wi-Fi VLAN. It may just be that your equipment doesn't have the capabilities that you need. The router seems capable of VLANs, but is your switch managed and capable of VLANs? If the Wi-Fi router can't do what you need, you may need to get a real AP.

Comment: The WiFi AP is a TPLink TD-W8968. It is currently set to ADSL Router Mode (but obv is not connected as an ADSL router). It is not dishing out the IPs, but is set to DHCP relay. Other operating modes for this router are "Wireless Router Mode" and "3G Router Mode". I'm guessing Wireless mode might be a bridge mode?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the switch is capable of this, but I was under the assumption it could be done just via the Vigor router? What do i  need to look for in regards to the switch?

Comment: The Wi-Fi router is a consumer-grade device, and thos types of questions are off-topic for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

If you need use the Wi-Fi router as an AP for one SSID, disable DHCP (server and relay) on the Wi-Fi router and connect it to the switch by a LAN port of Wi-Fi Router.

In this setup, Wi-Fi clients get an IP address from the LAN DHCP (I assume it is the main router "vigor").

Then do QoS on the router based on different client IP addresses. It switches the Wi-Fi router to an AP (bridge) mode.